# This sounds like a scam to me, am I wrong?

Tags: checking-account

This was an [article in the Penny Hoarder](https://www.thepennyhoarder.com/smart-money/bank-accounts/free-checking-account-aspiration/) about a California startup checking company called Aspiration that pays 1% interest that lets you choose how much you pay in “fees.” Is this garbage? It sounds like garbage.

Comment: @DStanley The blog post is indeed paid advertising (the links are all affiliate links), but I'm certain that the OP here is not a spammer, just curious.  That having been said, this has already been answered before, so I, too, have voted to close.

Comment: and.. it's a wrap.

Comment: My bad, forgot to check before I submitted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their [web site](https://www.aspiration.com/) ....

> Deposits insured by the FDIC up to $250,000 per depositor.

A tiny bit of research would confirm this, that they are a legit company.